# Boost Serialization equivalent in Python

Tags: python, c++, serialization, boost

I have a project where in there is an existing Cpp that uses boost serialization that serialize an xml file. I'm not allowed to change the existing Cp so I need to replicate in python what boost serialization is doing. Is there a library in python that has the same logic with boost serialization?

this sample output of boost serialization

`"22 serialization::archive 14 0 0 9 localhost 8888 0 0 0 0 1"`

Ps. I tried pickle but the output of pickle is not the same compare with boost serialization.

Comment: well then i miss the part that the CPP file parse the xml then serialize it using boost archive

Answer (score 2):

That doesn't look like XML. Rather it looks like it might be Boost's text archive format (you'd have to check).

Your options are going to include:

- Parse the text with code you've written
- Convince the author of the C++ code to use XML (which is easily handled in Python)
- Both use something like Google Protocol Buffers, or Avro, etc. This would have been the ideal choice at the outset, as it's the one that involves neither you or the author of the C++ code having to actually write any code. When planning on integrating heterogenous systems (i.e. C++ and Python), it's well worth picking a technology that is designed for the job (e.g. Google Protocol Buffers), i.e. something that supports heterogeneity.

In-langauge serialistions like Boost serialisation are generally the wrong way to go if the archive / stream has to be read in another language, because it means there is two places where code has to be written and maintained (in your case in the C++ and in the Python). That leads to increased effort (both of you have to write code) and increased risk (one of you might make a mistake).

In contrast using a serialisation technology that has a schema language and a code generator removes all this effort and risk entirely. For instance, for GPB you'd write a schema file (.proto), and compile that to both C++ code and also Python code. They'd use the C++, you'd use the Python, and you'd both automatically be serialising / deserialising from a common format specified by that .proto file.

If the content of the data being exchange between yourselves needs to change, you change the schema and recompile it. None of the C++ or Python code you write yourselves needs to be changed (other than to account for the extra message fields you've added in the .proto).

Comment: The XML archive format is just as proprietary as the text format. So even though the parser would read it as well formed XML (hopefully), it would be nigh impossible to usefully interpret. Consider Boost Python or Py++11 instead

Comment: Sorry i think i miss the part that the CPP file parse the xml file then serialize it. and you're correct that it is text archive format. The reason why we need to make a boost serialize like in python is that we need to replace a process that only deals with sending and receiving data. lets call it Process A. Process A deals with the serialize/deserialize data and pass it to the python class Lets call it Process B. then it will be send as socket to the Process C.

A<->B<->C

what we need is to remove Process A. and use B to deal with the serializing/deserializing of data

B<->A

Comment: @sehe, yes, the XML is still just as proprietary, but at least there's Python libraries that will do a good job of parsing it. Kinda a half-way house!

Comment: It's false hope. Trust me. For all but the most trivial object graphs.

Comment: @CedrickClemente, I'm afraid we still don't know what languages A, B and C are written in or what the interface formats between them are...

Comment: @sehe, oh yes I completely agree. If only there were a decent XSD-->POPO/POCO code generator.

Comment: Protobuf is decent - although the generated C++ code interface is atrocious (wrap that stuff :))

Comment: @sehe, yes it's OK. I've used commercial ASN.1 tools a lot, and believe me GPB's generated C++ classes are (in comparison) not bad at all. I do wish the creators of these things would use the STL... There's curiously few (like, none) ASN.1 --> Python compilers out there, which is a real nuisance, which is why I've not mentioned it thus far.

Comment: @bazza for the reference A and C is C++ codes. B is python.. the reason why they use B is that python is good in terms of socket. so they propose that remove A.. and put all the process of A in B.